# Dependency in pom.xml file. Don't import selenium libriaries

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I added to pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But in java file when I declare Webdriver driver; There is any proposition to import a libriary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You probably meant "import the Webdriver class from a library".

Answer (score 1):

You can use below dependency. The dependency that you are using isn't correct.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Java. 
All available versions. [Selenium Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java)

Selenium BOM (Bill of Materials)
This project intends to improve Selenium dependency management by specifying POM managing dependency versions for all Selenium artifacts.

[Description of Selenium BOM + how to use it.](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-selenium-bom)